# When I compile a "release" build of CLR C++ application I get a cmd window popping up in addition to the GUI. How do I resolve this?

Tags: c++, compilation, clr

here is my main function. Im not quite sure why this is happening (my first GUI application ever, Ive always done CLI before this). This does not happen when making Debug build, only with Release build. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and this is a Windows application:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace std;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
[STAThread]

int main()
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Project::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you specified "Command Line Application" in the Release Settings of your project. Try this: Create a new project (assuming you are Visual Studio) and select "GUI" as your project type. Then compare the settings to your current project.
When Windows loads a .exe, it looks at the metadata to determine, if it is a CMD or GUI application. The metadata is written by the linker.

Comment: That was it. Thank you. I didnt realize Debug and Released didnt share settings... for anyone with this in the future change Project Settings -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem to "Windows"